# SSIS package behavior when adding Columns to a Pipe delimited flat file with CRLF at the end

Tags: ssis

I have an existing SSIS package that loads data from Pipe delimited flat file source with CRLF at the end of the line to a database table destination.

If we add new columns to the source file but not to the destination table. Will the SSIS package fail? As per my testing, it fails but i just wanted to confirm that i didn't miss anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to update the source to identify the new columns, but then you can ignore them on the import, but you cant just change the file format without updating the meta data in the source.

Comment: @billinkc  Posted as answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment to answer:

You have to update the source to identify the new columns, but then you can ignore them on the import, but you cant just change the file format without updating the meta data in the source.